# Super Slow Checkout Issue

Tags: performance, magento, checkout

this is my first post. I have an issue with my Magento 1.9.1 websites checkout process, when a customer adds a product to the cart the website seems to hang and take around 10 seconds at first and then 5-7 seconds for every other product added.

I have done many things to speed up my website, I also hired an admin but we are both stumped. The website is www.AlterEgoFitness.co.uk

I have paid for a VPS and will be moving on to the VPS within a few days, I hope some one can help as this has been happening for over 3 months now and I do not know anywhere else to look. Thanks for reading

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you activate the default Magento theme?

Answer (score 0):

in Magento there are lots of order total modules and on checkout each of them gets executed.
Some of them are not in use so if you check XML and remove those unwanted order total modules that will improve speed.

This is applicable to all sites.
For e.g if you do not have recurring products then Nominal order total can be eliminated.

Comment: I see and which order total modules in particular? I have mage rss disabled in the mage xml file

Comment: Nominal order total can be eliminated.